# Irreducible space with infinitely many irreducible components

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

It would be intuitively satisfying to say the following:

> A topological space is irreducible if and only if it has exactly one irreducible component.

But it is not immediately clear how to prove $\Rightarrow$. Specifically, is it possible for an irreducible space to have infinitely many irreducible components?

Comment: If $X$ is irreducible, then $X$ is the unique maximal irreducible subset of $X$.

Comment: Could you clarify which category the space in question belongs to? Algebraic variety, topological space, anything elsE?

Comment: @Michael: it says right here that this is a topological space.

Comment: @tomasz: the tags include both general-topology and algebraic-geometry, with very different presumed spaces.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I believe that is an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: Of course! I asked a stupid question. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael: Very different? Every algebraic variety is a topological space, and irreducible spaces are studied *mostly* in algebraic geometry, so it makes sense to add the tag to draw attention of people acquainted with those. On the other hand, the question says clearly that it's about topological spaces.

Comment: There is only one category in sight: that of topological spaces. When algebraic geometers talk of irreducibility, irreducible components, Krull dimension,...  of a scheme $X$ they mean by definition the irreducibility, irreducible components, Krull dimension,...  of the underlying topological space $|X|$. The additional scheme structure on $|X|$ plays no role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you’re asking in a purely topological context, the argument is straightforward: if $X$ is an irreducible topological space, then $X$ is the unique maximal irreducible subset of $X$ and therefore the only irreducible component of $X$.

Comment: I guess a more nontrivial question would be this: is it true that a space is irreducible if and only if it *cannot* be covered by *proper* irreducible subspaces?

Comment: @ashpool: You’ll need to add some sort of non-triviality condition, since singletons are irreducible.